# How to get text from an html link in php

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink

How can I get the text from an html link ?
For example, if I have this form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <a href="test.php" name="link">Text to store</a>
</form>
```

how could I have something similar to echo $_POST['link'];

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question a little so we can understand it

Comment: Did you mean all a tags or specific ones with specific id or class?

Comment: I edited it, I wish you'll understand it now

Answer (score 3):

here we go

```
$myVar = strip_tags('<a href="test.php">Text I Want</a>');
```